How to handle notification actions on tapping push notification message in banner when app is closed/terminated
Received push notification when Flutter-iOS app is closed/terminated state and user click Allow/Deny action on tapping the push notification message, then app gets openup up but not able to get hold of the clicked action and related push notification payload inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions callback method of AppDelegate.m
Can you please tell how do we handle above case Flutter-iOS app is closed state?
I tried same usecase on in native iOS app (non-flutter app), I noticed didFinishLaunchingWithOptions first gets invoked and after that didReceiveNotificationResponse invoked when clicked notification action defined on push notification in the banner. Inside didReceiveNotificationResponse method/callback we can get hold of action and its payload.
Can you please tell me flutter iOS app should have the same behaviour? or We have to handle it differently?
